# Additional row while aggregating based on value

Tags: qlikview

This is how my data model looks like:

```
Id          Status             StartDate
1           StatusA            01/01/2015
1           StatusB            01/03/2015
1           StatusC            01/05/2015
2           StatusA            01/04/2015
2           StatusB            01/08/2015
```

I am trying to get the max date of StatusB column per Id.

This is how my dimension looks like:

```
=If(Match(Status,'StatusB'),Timestamp(StartDate))
```

It works fine but it also gives me an additional duplicate row with Empty max date.

My Straight Chart table contains only these 2 columns. If i remove the Max Date dimension, it shows one record per Id

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add the filter in the dimension. QV allow calculated dimension but they can cause a lot of performance issues. (basically when calculated dimensions are used QV is createing new "virtual" table in the memory with the new dimension. With big datasets this can drain your ram/cpu)

For this cases its much better to "control" the dimension through the expressions. In your case just add Status as dimension and type the following expression:

```
max( {< Status = {'StatusB'} >} StartDate)
```

And in Numbers tab change the format setting to Timestamp.

Stefan

Comment: Works great but it hides the rows that does not have 'StatusB'.

Answer (score 0):

you can look like this;

aggr(max(StartDate), Status, StartDate)